# Exclusive set Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have list of checkboxes (using ng-repeat) that have values Owner, Manager, Supervisor, Shareholder, Partner, Corporate Officer. I am creating validation rules that will only allow multi-select options for the following combinations. For instance, Owner and Supervisor or Owner and Manager combinations are allowed to multi select where as Manager and Supervisor are not allowed to select together. Similarly for other conditions.

- Owner/ Supervisor
- Owner/ Manager
- Shareholder/ Supervisor
- Shareholder/ Manager
- Partner/ Supervisor
- Partner/ Manager
- Officer/Shareholder
- Officer/ Shareholder/ Supervisor
- Officer/ Shareholder/ Manager

I've tried - if Owner is selected I disable every other options except Manager and Supervisor. This doesnt work for all the scenarios.

What is the best approach in angularJS to solve it? any help would be much appreciated.

I dont have working copy of my script. Here is what I tried

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 two-col" data-ng-class="error">
        <div class="checkbox"
             data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in types"
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       id="{{key}}"
                       name="test"
                       data-ng-click="vm.checkDisabled(vm.selected, key, vm.isDisabled, vm.validationRules)"
                       data-ng-true-value="'{{key}}'"
                       data-ng-model="vm.selected[key]"
                       data-ng-required="true">
                {{value.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



function checkDisabled(model, key, disabledValues, validation) {
            var exclusiveset = validation[key];
            if (typeof exclusiveset != 'undefined') {
                if (model[key]) {
                    for (var key in disabledValues) {
                        if (exclusiveset.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                            disabledValues[key] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (!isSelected(model)) {
                    for (var key in disabledValues) {
                        disabledValues[key] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

validation rules is a json file. If Owner is selected, other options will be disabled except Supervisor.
    "Owner"  : ["officer", "partner", "shareholder"],
    "manager"   : ["officer", "partner", "supervisor"],

Comment: First, show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: Can you please share the script?

Comment: Please share the  " types "  array

Comment: well if owner is selected then Supervisor enabled.So, user can select Supervisor which enable the 'Shareholder'  'Officer' which are not allowed by owner.What is this scenario ?

Comment: Correct that's my problem. The scenario is that, I should only provide multi-select for owner and supervisor or owner and manager. User cannot select owner, manager, supervisor at the same time.

Comment: Types array is {'owner': 'owner', 'manager':'manager'} and so on for other four values.